# Animated view doesn't receive touch events after animating over another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a third party grid I use for data entry from `Infragistics`, called `IGGridView`.  It is the yellow rectangle in the picture.

I'm trying my hand at some animation and simply wanted to move the grid to the left 300 points over a few seconds.

Before I do any animation, my grid is scrollable, it's cells are touchable, and when tapped, present an editor to edit the cell value.

However, after animation, the most bizarre thing happens that I didn't expect at all.  The underlapped view which the yellow rectangle grid is now over, still receives all its touch events, RIGHT THROUGH THE GRID, but the grid receives nothing at all.  It won't scroll, nor are its cells tappable.  It's like the grid died after it animated.
I thought perhaps it was because even though the grid appeared on top, it wasn't really on top, so I added a completion handler and did a `bringSubviewToFront` call, but still nothing.  Note, if I touch the grid on the far right where it's not overlapping the other view to its left, the grid still receives its touches and I can scroll it and edit a cell (a rightmost cell anyway).  So it's like the grid is obscured by the view that it OVERlapped.

What is going on there?

**My animation code is on a swipe left gesture.**

```
-(void)handleSwipeLeftRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {            
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
            grid1.frame = CGRectMake(-300, 0, 340, self.view.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            grid1.frame = CGRectMake(-300, 0, 340, self.view.frame.size.height);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:grid1];
        }];
    }
```

**Before animation, it looks like this.**

[image]

**After animation it looks like this.**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this with a non third-party control to see if that's the problem?

Comment: @Code No, I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I forgot that I have my grid placed on top of a transparent view, and it's mostly moved outside that transparent view when I animate it, so I'm getting all my touch stuff cut off on the portion of the grid that has been moved outside its underlying view.

Comment: So this is an answer ?